# Finding distance between points using Python

Tags: python, point, distance, shapely, fiona

I have a shapefile containing 10 test points like so:

[image]

The spatial reference is 2157 - Irish Transverse Mercator

I am wanting to find the distance between each point in Python. Ideally, something like so [Finding points that are within a set distance of other points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91571/finding-points-that-are-within-a-set-distance-of-other-points)

I tried the below code using `fiona` and `shapely` as a starting point

```py
import fiona
import shapely.geometry


with fiona.open(r'c:/test/points.shp') as src:
    for feature in src:
        geom = shapely.geometry.shape(feature["geometry"])
        distance_between_pts = geom.distance(geom)
        print(distance_between_pts)
```

However this just prints 0.0 ten times.

I'm not sure how to find the distance between each point. Or even if I were able to pick a point and return the points which fall within a certain distance would help

Comment: Your query asks for the distance between a point and itself, so zero is the correct answer. If you want to compare each point with the other points you need to nest the queries.

Comment: @Vince im not quite sure how to

Comment: That's a Python programming task. Best practice for small numbers of features is to cache them in a list and double nest the `for` loops O(n^2/2)

Answer (score 4):

As @Vince notes in a comment:

> Your query asks for the distance between a point and itself, so zero
> is the correct answer. If you want to compare each point with the
> other points you need to nest the queries.

However, rather than an actual nested loop, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to simplify the code:

```py
from itertools import product
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape


with fiona.open(r'points.shp') as src:
    for feat1, feat2 in product(src, repeat=2):
        id1, id2 = feat1['id'], feat2['id']

        if id1 == id2: # Don't measure distance against itself.
            continue

        geom1, geom2 = shape(feat1["geometry"]), shape(feat2["geometry"])
        distance_between_pts = geom1.distance(geom2)
        print(id1, id2, distance_between_pts)
```

Output:

```sh
0 1 210
0 2 1250
0 3 1102
0 4 846
1 0 210
1 2 1090
1 3 978
1 4 752
2 0 1250
2 1 1090
2 3 290
2 4 534
3 0 1102
3 1 978
3 2 290
3 4 283
4 0 846
4 1 752
4 2 534
4 3 283
```

Or if you don't want duplicates (e.g 0->1 and 1->0 distance), you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
from itertools import combinations
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape

with fiona.open(r'points.shp') as src:
    for feat1, feat2 in combinations(src, r=2):
        id1, id2 = feat1['id'], feat2['id']

        geom1, geom2 = shape(feat1["geometry"]), shape(feat2["geometry"])
        distance_between_pts = geom1.distance(geom2)
        print(id1, id2, int(distance_between_pts))
```

Output:

```sh
0 1 210
0 2 1250
0 3 1102
0 4 846
1 2 1090
1 3 978
1 4 752
2 3 290
2 4 534
3 4 283
```

Comment: Do you know why it is still needed to type `r` i.e. `fiona.open(r'points.shp')`? Simply `fiona.open('points.shp')`. Or it is a mode, that is mentioned here https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#reading-vector-data?

Comment: It's not needed, there's no backslashes.